# Actualizar mi datatable sin recargar para filtrado de busqueda (Laravel , Blade, Ajax)

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, datatables, laravel-blade

Tengo  tabla en mi vista blade la estoy creando con el datatable trayendo la api mediante ajax , estoy pensando hacer un form que actualice el contenido de la tabla con el filtro de busqueda pero mi duda es como poder volver a recargar la vista con el filtro si la tengo la api estatica en mi datatable.

```
var table = $('#kt_table').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>",
            ajax:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/industrias_dt",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'industria_nombre'},
                {data: 'industria_usuario_modificacion_id'},
                {data: 'updated_at', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'industria_estado_id', className: 'kt-align-center'},
                {data: 'btn', className: 'kt-align-center', responsivePriority: -1},
            ],],
        });
```

Este es mi form

```
<form>
   @csrf
   <input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre">
   <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria">
   <button type="submit">
     Buscar
   </button>
</form>
```

Esta es mi api

```
public function industria()
    {
        return datatables()
        ->of(industria::all())
        ->addColumn('btn','botones.industria-btn')
        ->rawColumns(['btn'])
        ->toJson();
    }
```

Comment: Has probado con `$('#kt_table').ajax.reload();`?

Comment: Eso solo habria recargado la tabla pero yo necesitaba era carga la tabla con un request de la busqueda .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione primero en mi api tuve que meter el request

```
public function tipo_documento(Request $request)
    {
        $arreglo = $request->ids;
        $nombre = $arreglo[0];
        $estado = $arreglo[1];


            return datatables()
        ->of(tipo_documento::where('tipo_documento_nombre','LIKE',"%$nombre%")->get())
        ->addColumn('btn','botones.tipo-documento-btn')
        ->rawColumns(['btn'])
        ->toJson();           
        
    }
```

capture los valores en code para pasarlo en el ajax , data: code

```
var request = [];
request.push($('#txtNombre').val());
request.push($('#indEstado').val());
var code = {ids: request}
```

Al momento de pasar la peticion por ajax en el success  tuve que limpiar la tabla y volver a pintarlo con lo que me devolvia la api.

```
success: function (response)
                    {
                        $('#kt_table').DataTable().clear().draw();
                        $('#kt_table').DataTable().rows.add(response.data).draw();    
                  
                    },
```